# What is the use of "being" in the sentence grammatically?

Tags: clauses, present-participles

In the sentence:

> Major refreshes to the OS come about every six months, with the most recent **being** the May 2019 Update.

What is the use of "being" grammatically? 
Can any words be added between "recent" and "being"?

Comment: What would you suggest instead? It's not the best writing but being is used like that a lot. He won many races, the latest one being the 20-km race.OR: The latest one was x.

Answer (score 1):

"being" is the **verb(-ing)** of your 2nd clause. You can separate the sentence into 2 as follows:

> Major refreshes to the OS come about every six months. The most recent one **is** the May 2019 Update.

You *can* add a noun (mainly the subject) between "recent" and "being". For example:

> ..., with the most recent **refresh** being the May 2019 update

However, that is not recommended as it repeats the word "refresh".

Comment: You can add a number  of nouns between "recent" and "being": update, patch, release, example...all work, as would any other synonym in context. I agree with you about the rest though.

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnZhau has correctly stated, "being" in this context is a verb, an "action word", the present participle conjugation of the irregularly conjugating verb "to be", which means "to exist", especially in a specified form, state, or location.

Note that "being" can also a noun in other contexts, meaning one's existence or nature, as well living things (e.g. human beings, sentient beings).